# Why batch normalization does not stop gradient in the calculation of mean and variance?

Tags: deep-learning, neural-network, batch-normalization

In my understanding, BN provides weight scale invariance in the backpropagation process, and as a consequence, stabilizes the training process. Out of curiosity, I am wondering why BN does not stop gradient in the calculation of mean and variance since doing so won't change this property?

Comment: What does "stopping the gradient" mean?

Comment: Prevent gradients of mean and variance being considered in back-prop.

Comment: I am also wondering why. It is a bit discussed here: https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/batchnorm-and-back-propagation/65765

Comment: See my answer here: https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/526072/171816